# Proving that 2 vectors exist that satisfy an equation

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having trouble with the following problem: 
[image]

It gives a hint to specify the vectors with formulas involving `a, b`, this is where I have gotten to:

```
v1(a+b) = z
v2(a+b) = z

v1(a+b) - v2(a+b) = 0

(v1 - v2)(a+b) = 0
```

Now the above equation is a heterogeneous vector space, therefore [0,0,0] must be one of the vectors. Then I get stuck, what do I need to do next, am I even on the right track?

Answer (score 1):

To determine the value of $\,z\,$ in $\,z=ax+by$, we must choose one value for $\,x\,$ and one value for $\,y$.

Hence, $\,x,\,y\,$ are "free independent variables" for us to choose. In other words, we can generate the whole set of points satisfying the equation by choosing all the possible values of $\,x\,$ and $\,y$.

So how to choose all possible values for $\,x,\,y\,$?

Since $\,x,\,y\,$ are independent, we let $\,x=1\,$ while $\,y=0\,$ so that $\,y\,$ will no longer "affect" $\,x\,$. As a result, the first vector $\,v_1\,$ should be

$$v_1=(1,0,a)$$

As you can see, if we multiply $\,v_1$ by any real constant, we can run through all the possibilities of $\,x$.

Next, we set $\,x=0\,$ and $\,y=1$, which gives the second vector $\,v_2\,$

$$v_2=(0,1,b)$$

This time, we can get all the possibilities of $\,y\,$ by multiplying $\,v_2\,$ by any real constant.

Together, the linear combinations of $\,v_1$ and $\,v_2$ will give us all the possibilities of $\,x\,$ and $\,y\,$. So the whole set of points satisfying the equation will be the set

$$\lambda v_1+\mu v_2$$

where $\,\lambda,\,\mu\,$ are real constants.

( This result is reasonable because$\ \ \lambda v_1+\mu v_2=(\lambda,\,\mu,\,a\lambda+b\mu)\ $)